# Trigger Describe Record Type Error

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign, describesobject

I have encountered a small problem and would love some assistance.

Within my trigger (line 16) i have hard coded my campaign record type in. When i delete the campaign with a campaign member with status of "Sent"  then i am expected results.

Reading different forums i am under the impression that i can use a "Describe" to get record Type Id without SOQL. I have include this into the trigger line (11 & 17). However when i test deleting a campaign with a campaign member of "Sent"  then i am getting this error message

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex
> trigger CampaignBeforeDelete caused an unexpected exception, contact
> your administrator: CampaignBeforeDelete: execution of BeforeDelete
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
> object: Trigger.CampaignBeforeDelete: line 11, column 1".

This is my trigger

```
Trigger CampaignBeforeDelete on Campaign (before delete) {

    List<Campaign> delCampaign = trigger.old;
    Id CampRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NameOfRecordType').getRecordTypeId();
    Boolean dontDelete = False;
    for (Campaign eachCampaign : delCampaign)
    {
        //Any campaign where there are campaign members with status "sent" 
        //If (eachCampaign.RecordTypeId == '01258000000OnDL')
        if(eachCampaign.RecordTypeId == 'CampRecordTypeId' )
        {                 
            List<CampaignMember> cMs = [SELECT id, status FROM CampaignMember
                WHERE CampaignId = :eachCampaign.Id];

            For (CampaignMember eachCM : cMS)
            {
                If (eachCM.Status == 'Sent')
                {dontDelete = True;}
            }
            If (dontDelete)
                eachCampaign.adderror('Cannot delete a campaign that has members with status Sent');
        }
    }
}
```

This is a list of RT for campaigns. i need to trigger to work on any of those rts
[image: Campaignrt]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53868/discussion-on-question-by-masond3-trigger-describe-record-type-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 11 in your code points to a bracket, so I can't help you with that. But your code seems a little wrong to me. First of all you are querying records inside a loop, and that is bad practice. Second: you have unnecessary `if`s, if I understood correctly your code. Third: it is also bad practice to hardcode the Ids of your record types.

The following trigger will handle the deletion of the Campaign object, detect if the campaign being deleted has a specific record type, and if so, it will check if the child records (Campaign Members) have that status ('Sent'). If so, then it will prevent the deletion of that campaign.

```
trigger CampaignBeforeDelete on Campaign (before delete) {
    Id myRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NameOfRecordType').getRecordTypeId();

    List<Id> campaing_ids = new List<Id>();

    for (Campaign c : Trigger.old) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == myRecordType) {
            campaing_ids.add(c.Id);
        }
    }

    List<CampaignMember> members = [SELECT Id, Status, CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId IN :campaing_ids];

    for (Campaign c : Trigger.old) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == myRecordType) {
            for (CampaignMember member : members) {
                if (member.CampaignId == c.Id) {
                    if (member.Status == 'Sent') {
                        c.adderror('Cannot delete a campaign that has members with status \'Sent\'');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53867/discussion-on-answer-by-renato-oliveira-trigger-describe-record-type-error).